# OpenSuse 11.4 hard free space decreases to zero without any running program

Tags: linux, hard-drive, vnc, opensuse, linux-server

I have a one-user linux OpenSuse 11.4 on my HP proliant server and I always connect to it with TightVCN. The server settings are:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 508283
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 55311708
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 508283
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 92324960
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I had not this problem before but, recently, with or without any uses, the hard free space rapidly decreases until it reaches to zero (during less than 24 hours). There is no big file when this thing happens. Just free space finish and I do not know where it might have gone. There is not stable uses of free space, because when I restart it twice, It would comes back. When this declination starts the VNC connection losses without any warnings (Even, with no VNC connection this thing happens). It forced me to reset server manually. The first restarting restore VNC connection and the second restarting could restore the lost free space. This cycle never stops. Therefore, I would like to know how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean harddisk free space is getting lower and lower. The only option for this to happen is that someone or something is writing to a file constantly. Usually the culprit is some misconfigured daemon.

Similar situation i've seen beeing pcsc-lite (cryptocards related) was set to do an excessive logging and firefox was constantly polling it. this resulted in being logged to the .xsession-errors. Which is rotated on GUI restart.

First things first:

- get yourself at least a bit familiar with ssh/openssh/PuTTY
- stop all gui (the login daemon should be enough (gdm))
- start connecting to the server via ssh and monitor status

In order to try and debug the issue the following (when it occurs) will help:

- get a list of the open files ( **lsof > /tmp/list_of_open_files** in terminal as root )
- look for large files ( **find {/path/to/directory/} -type f -size +{size-in-kb}k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'** )

Comment: No one could connect to the server except me. No large files exist when this happens. Just free space finish in a less than 24 hours. I do not know where it might have gone. Even If no program runs this thing happens. I have never encountered it before. It happens recently.

Comment: my first suspect would be hidden logs for the Xserver. Try to stop it and manage the server for a while with ssh (as a bonus this will free some memory)

Comment: Even with SSH connection I have encountered this. I formatted the server and reinstalled all programs. After 3 days this thing happened again. Is there any possibility in getting viruses? That is weird

Comment: Possibility always. In reality a bit hard. if you want i can try and take a look at the box itself.